# Delete a large pattern from one list

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have this list:IndividualsPossible

```
ind = 40;
StrategiesCop = {{"1", "c", "d", "r", "r"}, {"1", "c", "d", "nr", 
"r"}, {"1", "d", "d", "r", "r"}, {"1", "d", "d", "nr", "r"}, {"2",
 "d", "c", "r", "r"}, {"2", "d", "c", "r", "nr"}, {"2", "d", "d", 
"r", "r"}, {"2", "d", "d", "r", "nr"}};
IndividualsPossible = 
Table[{RandomChoice[{"1", "2"}], RandomChoice[{"c", "d"}], 
RandomChoice[{"c", "d"}], RandomChoice[{"r", "nr"}], 
RandomChoice[{"r", "nr"}]}, {i, 1, 4*ind}];
```

and I need to delete some elements that I don´t need from all possible combinations

```
{"1", "c", "d", "nr", "nr"}, {"1", "c", "d", "r", "nr"}, {"1", "d", \
"d", "nr", "nr"}, {"1", "d", "d", "r", "nr"}, {"2", "d", "c", "r", \
"r"}, {"2", "d", "c", "r", "nr"}, {"2", "d", "d", "r", "r"}, {"2", \
"d", "d", "r", "nr"}
```

I tried with `DeleteCases` but this delete one each time.

Comment: You gave examples of what you want removed, yet you didn't say the criterion satisfied by the elements you want to remove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lst = {{"1", "c", "d", "r", "r"}, {"1", "c", "d", "nr", "r"}, {"1", "d", "d", "r", "r"}, 
  {"1", "d", "d", "nr", "r"}, {"2", "d", "c",  "r", "r"}, {"2", "d", "c", "r", "nr"}, 
  {"2", "d", "d", "r",  "r"}, {"2", "d", "d", "r", "nr"}};
del = {{"2", "d", "c", "r", "nr"}, {"2", "d", "d", "r", "r"}, {"2", "d", "d", "r", "nr"}};

DeleteCases[lst, Alternatives @@ del]
```

> {{"1", "c", "d", "r", "r"}, {"1", "c", "d", "nr", "r"}, {"1", "d", 
>         "d", "r", "r"}, {"1", "d", "d", "nr", "r"}, {"2", "d", "c", "r", 
>         "r"}}

Or

```
Complement[lst, del]
```

> {{"1", "c", "d", "nr", "r"}, {"1", "c", "d", "r", "r"}, {"1", "d", 
>     "d", "nr", "r"}, {"1", "d", "d", "r", "r"}, {"2", "d", "c", "r", 
>     "r"}}

Or

```
lst /. Alternatives @@ del -> Sequence[]
```

> {{"1", "c", "d", "r", "r"}, {"1", "c", "d", "nr", "r"}, {"1", "d", 
>     "d", "r", "r"}, {"1", "d", "d", "nr", "r"}, {"2", "d", "c", "r", 
>     "r"}}

Comment: If I don´t want to create manually the del list, what can I do?

Comment: @Lina, then, as mentioned by J.M., you need to specify the " criterion satisfied by the elements you want to remove".